# Diagnose slow loading page in PHP/WordPress/WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, woocommerce

I am having inordinately long load times while using WordPress / WooCommerce / PHP for ordering items. External sources do not seem to be the issue, as this is what New Relic is reporting:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mROHU.png

I enabled slow query logging but that turned up nothing, and my site is on Digital Ocean SSDs with 1 GB of RAM and PHP is getting 96 MB of RAM. The New Relic dashboard is not very helpful, nor is the Chrome Developer Tool (it just says the POSTed page is taking 15+ seconds).

Is there a good way to analyze what PHP files are being called during the huge delay? I think it has to be somewhere in PHP, but I have no idea where to take a look beyond the dev tools, New Relic, and slow query logging (obviously not a DB problem).

Comment: IIRC setting time limit on PHP to less then 15secs will show you were it timed out, maybe it is a way to debug.

Comment: Also, this screenshot of new relic show's nothing unusual, everything is in a few miliseconds..

Comment: Er... are you missing the 9000ms+ calls to index.php?

Comment: ops, right.. I saw it as 9.something ms, sorry.

Comment: Maybe do something like this before each call then check the logs? `error_log("Method: $method Time: ".microtime(true));`

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the P3 plugin and run a site scan.   This will break down the render time by plugin.